# How to build a filter module with multiple checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, filter

I've a form with multiple checkboxes and a list which will be filtered according checked values. I can filter according to one value but when two values check, it won't work properly.

I've shared sample for practice below and [here is jsFiddle also.](http://jsfiddle.net/utj5g8ne/)

When you select **A** and **B** together and submit form, you will inspect, **C** is coming also.

```js
$('form').submit(function() {
  $(this).find('input[data-type]').each(function(key,val) {
    if ( val.checked ) {
      // get checked input's data type
      var checkedType = $(this).data('type');

      // hide items which doesn't match with current type
      $('ul').find('li').show().filter(function() {
        return $(this).find('a[data-'+ checkedType +'="true"]').length == 0;
      }).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label>
    <input data-type="a" type="checkbox" />
    <b>A</b>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input data-type="b" type="checkbox" />
    <b>B</b>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input data-type="c" type="checkbox" />
    <b>C</b>
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</form>

<ul>
  <li>
    <a data-a="true" data-b="false" data-c="false">A</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-a="false" data-b="true" data-c="false">B</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-a="false" data-b="false" data-c="true">C</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-a="true" data-b="true" data-c="false">A, B</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-a="true" data-b="false" data-c="true">A, C</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-a="false" data-b="true" data-c="true">B, C</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the list with B, C is showing up because according to your script atleast one of them is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after a slight work around i think i got it working

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  var  checkedType = [];
  $(this).find('input[data-type]').each(function(key,ele) {
    if (ele.checked)      
      checkedType.push($(ele).data('type'));
  });

    $('ul').find('li').show();

    $.each(checkedType, function(i, e){
        $('ul').find('a[data-'+ e + '="false"]').parent("li").hide();
    });

    return false;
});
```

[hope this is what you need](http://jsfiddle.net/utj5g8ne/2/)

but if you need function for filter, im helpless